# Summation Changes Based on Result

Tags: excel, math, google-sheets

My objective is to do a sum of previous values based on ranges.

I have an index of 0 to 25. I have a base rate at index 0 to be 0.142857.

The final result is a percentage. I have 3 formula's I know...

1. Base Rate * 0.1 is the increment if the result is <30%
2. Base Rate * 0.02 is the increment if the result is <32%
3. If the result is above 32%, do nothing else, show it as a hard cap of 32%

So for example:

[image]

So the problem is that I hardcoded column C with the increment per index. I need this to be smart enough to know, hey if this would go above 30% then use the next formula and if it would go above 32% then cap it. Any ideas on how I could do this in Excel or Google Sheets without using scripts or VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B3** and drag down:

```
=IF(IF(B2< 30%, B2+($B$2*0.1)) < 30%, B2+($B$2*0.1),
 IF(IF(B2< 32%, B2+($B$2*0.02))< 32%, B2+($B$2*0.02),
 IF(IF(B2>=32%, B2+($B$2*0.02))>=32%, 32%)))
```

[image: 0]

---

cell **C2** could be: `=ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT(B2:B27, "00.00%")})`

Comment: This is answers my question perfectly, just a quick question, my breakpoints aren't static sadly, so it's not at 30% or 32% but rather.. What i know is that it's the next value after the last valid point. So for example, if my last value was 29.9999. That doesn't get rounded, instead the next value 0.302856 would be the LAST cell which would still use the first break points formula. So the first value in 30% still uses the below 30% breakpoint. If that makes sense. But to understand your formula, you're looking at the previous value to determine what the current value should do?

Comment: yes, formula always looks on the previous row and compare it to 30%/32%. I see... I could tweak it I guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(B2< 30%, B2+($B$2*0.1),
 IF(B2< 32%, B2+($B$2*0.02),
 IF(B2>=32%, 32%)))
```

[image: 0]

---

or combo:

```
=IF(B2< 30%, B2+($B$2*0.1),
 IF(IF(B2< 32%, B2+($B$2*0.02))< 32%, B2+($B$2*0.02),
 IF(IF(B2>=32%, B2+($B$2*0.02))>=32%, 32%)))
```

[image: 0]